# Google Alert Daily Digest as RSS

Tags: python, rss, beautifulsoup, feed, google-alerts

We can use Google to make alerts for us. I have made some 10 alerts, and because I was "spammed" with messages, I used the "Daily Digest" option; I now get every day in the morning a single message with all the alerts. Note that the separate alerts have the option to convert the alert to an RSS feed, but not the combined one.

However, I really do not like how this email is structured, and I'd much prefer to somehow see this as an RSS that I can read with some RSS reader.

I tried using Python to collect the email, and have used lxml and bs4 to parse it, but it is so incredibly messy and inconsistent to parse.

Does anyone know of a way to create a nice rss feed out of it (title, body, link)?

I'm able to extract the html from the email, [here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=f6tcjBUu) is a simple to work with html for those interested.

```
sp = BeautifulSoup('path/to/html')
for span in sp.findAll('span'):
    link = span.find('a')
    if link is not None and hasattr(link, 'href'):
        print(link.text)
```

It gets me 22 link texts, even though I have 17 posts.

The problem is that even the links and text are not consistently placed.

This is as close as I got with `lxml.html`:

```
tr = lxml.html.fromstring('path/to/html')
links = tr.xpath('//table/tr/td/div/span/a')

len(links) == 16    # not 17
True
```

Comment: Why not use the Google Alertrs RSS feeds directly? And then plug them in a tool like [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/recipes)?

Comment: @JulienGenestoux How to create those? I do not see how to make the RSS feeds. All I know is the Google Alerts where I can set them up, but that's sending them as email not RSS feeds.

Answer (score 1):

Create the alert first. You can then choose your method of delivery by dropping down the 'Deliver to' box. There are two options to choose from - email or RSS feed.